# why Angular can't get value in my situation

Tags: angular

I have an object and code below:

```
SeaWall: ProInfoSeawallBaseDto = new ProInfoSeawallBaseDto();
```

html below(SeaWallBase contain the propety 'final_Crest_Altitude')

```
 <input type="text" name="final_Crest_Altitude" [(ngModel)]="SeaWall.final_Crest_Altitude">
```

when I get the value

```
 console.log(this.SeaWall.final_Crest_Altitude);
```

the web console showed 'undefined'.
I am really confuse about it. I used the ngModel, it should be binded. My workmate have the same issue.
But, when I change the object name 'SeaWall' to 'SeaWallBase', everything's fine. 
Is 'SeaWall' a key name ?

Comment: You are creating the variable by name SeaWall the why you are using SeaWallBase in console.log ?

Comment: that's my fault.I just copy my code for my project.At first,I used the 'SeaWall',but now,I used the 'SeaWallBase'.Thx for your tip.

Comment: Still this is confusing. You are talking about `SeaWall` and `SeaWallBase` in your question.

Comment: Shortly,When I name a object as `SeaWall`,I can't get the value from it.But when I change it's name as `SeaWallBase`,then I can get the value form It successfully.So,I don't know why the name `SeaWall` failed.(Acuatlly,I suspect sometiomes ng could be 'crazy').

Comment: well it's impossible to diagnose the problem based on this code. Please reproduce the issue in a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is undefined because you have to initialize your object inside NgOnInit method.

I suggest you to read the life cycle of Angular : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: There was a person told me the solution yesterday.But it is disappeared now.I just started use the SO web.Can u explain this phenomenon?